# Is it possible to do an iterative string replace in an Azure ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I suspect it's not possible to do what I'm looking for but it's worth a shot!

I have a pipeline for provisioning Azure log query alert rules. The individual alert rules are defined as ARM parameter files, and I use a shared ARM template file to deploy them.

Here's a stripped down version of my template file with most of the parameters omitted.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "logQuery": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Query to execute against the AI resource"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "appInsightsResourceId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/','microsoft.insights/components/', parameters('appInsightsResourceName'))]",
        "actionGroupId": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/','microsoft.insights/actionGroups/', parameters('actionGroupName'))]",
        "linkToAiResource" : "[concat('hidden-link:', variables('appInsightsResourceId'))]"
    },
    "resources":[{
        "name":"[parameters('alertName')]",
        "type":"Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
        "location": "northeurope",
        "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
        "tags": {
            "[variables('linkToAiResource')]": "Resource"
        },
        "properties":{
           "description": "[parameters('alertDescription')]",
           "enabled": "[parameters('isEnabled')]",
           "source": {
               "query": "[parameters('logQuery')]",
               "dataSourceId": "[variables('appInsightsResourceId')]",
               "queryType":"[parameters('logQueryType')]"
           },
          "schedule":{
               "frequencyInMinutes": "[parameters('alertSchedule').Frequency]",
               "timeWindowInMinutes": "[parameters('alertSchedule').Time]"    
           },
           "action":{
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
                "severity": "[parameters('alertSeverity')]",
                "aznsAction":{
                    "actionGroup":"[array(variables('actionGroupId'))]"
                },
                "trigger":{
                    "thresholdOperator":"[parameters('alertTrigger').Operator]",
                    "threshold":"[parameters('alertTrigger').Threshold]"
                }
            }
         }
       }
    ]
}
```

You can see how I'm providing the App Insights query as a parameter, so my parameters file could look something like:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0", 
    "parameters": {
        "logQuery": {
            "value": "requests | where resultCode >= 500"
        }
    }
}
```

However, these queries can be very long and hard to understand when viewing as an unbreakable JSON string. So I want to parametize this parameter (if you know what I mean) so that the key variables are defined and supplied separately. I was thinking about changing the parameters to something like this, introducing a new parameter holding an array of placeholder replacements for the parametized query...

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0", 
    "parameters": {
        "logQueryVariables": [
            { "{minCode}": "500" }
        ],
        "logQuery": {
            "value": "requests | where resultCode >= {minCode}"
        }
    }
}
```

...then finding a way to iterate over the variables array and replace the placeholders in the `logQuery` parameter, I thought maybe I could use an ARM function or something. But I'm afraid to admit I'm stuck with this part. Is it possible to use the `copy` syntax to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

depends on what the end result should look like you can do this different ways, but I'd suggest against doing this in the template and suggest you do this outside of the template and feed in the result. If you really want to achieve exactly what you describe you can do that** with nested deployments. I dont think there is any other way of iterating through an array to build a string in ARM Templates.

Comment: Thanks. I did suspect it'd be impossible. My ideal is to drive everything from the parameters file to keep the template and build steps generic, but thanks for the idea. I've been trying a recursive ARM function but it's not allowed!

Comment: yeah, you'd need to use a nested deployment as a function basically, and feed input one by one and gather output and pass previous deployment output as input as well. if you have trouble with that - you can get back here and ask another question. i'd be able to write it up

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I could come. We do the input looping in powershell for secretObjects.

```
 {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
```

> "name": "[concat(variables('KeyVaultName'), '/',
>   variables('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretName)]",

```
"apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', variables('KeyVaultName'))]"
      ],
      "copy": {
        "name": "secretsCopy",
        "count": "[length(variables('secretsObject').secrets)]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "value": "[variables('secretsObject').secrets[copyIndex()].secretValue]"
      }
    }
```